# Set minDate field based on another calendar in datetimepicker

Tags: jquery, calendar, datetimepicker

I am using datetimepicker for showing calendar

I have two calendar field, which has cal1 and cal2 class

```
<input type="text" class="form-control cal1" id="from_search" name="from_search" required/>
<input type="text" class="form-control cal2" id="to_search" name="to_search" required />  

$(".cal1").datetimepicker({
        timepicker: false,
        format: "d-m-Y",
         onChangeDateTime: function(current_time, $input) {
            $input.data("Date", current_time.getTime());
            $(this).hide();
        },
        maxDate:'+1970/01/01'
    });

    // Date TimePicker
    $(".cal2").datetimepicker({
        timepicker: false,
        format: "d-m-Y",
         onChangeDateTime: function(current_time, $input) {
            $input.data("Date", current_time.getTime());
            $(this).hide();
        },
        maxDate:'+1970/01/01' //,
        //minDate: new Date()
    });
```

When we are selecting cal2, calendar have to show minDate based on cal1 calendar

I have google it. I have been getting for datepicker not for datetimepicker

How can i set minDate based on first calendar by using datetimepciker

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$(function () {
        $('.cal1').datetimepicker();
        $('.cal1').datetimepicker({
            useCurrent: false
        });
        $(".cal1").on("dp.change", function (e) {
            $('.cal2').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
        });
        $(".cal2").on("dp.change", function (e) {
            $('.cal1').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);
        });
    });
```

It is a pretty much self explanatory code, comment doubts if any!

Comment: Because All functions are accessed via the data attribute e.g. `$('#datetimepicker').data("DateTimePicker").FUNCTION()`

Comment: And here you are not setting the data attribute, it is a getter function.

Comment: what is dp.change? event is not invoking here

Comment: Which datetimepicker you using? Can you share a link?